# Get Text including the HTML Tags XML Parsing Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have an XML data like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Result>
<Status>OK</Status>
   <DisplayName>Az-Zahra Madressah</DisplayName>
   <Announcements>
      <Announcement>
         <Id>46</Id>
         <Title>AZM Dates</Title>
         <Description>
            <strong>December 21st, 28th; Winter Break</strong>
            ~ January 4th: Madressah and
            <strong>Acadamy ResumesAZM</strong>
            will provide snacks every first Sunday of the month.
         </Description>
         <Attachments />
      </Announcement>
   </Announcements>
   <Resources>
      <Resource>
         <Id>26</Id>
         <Title>Quran Competition Audio FIles</Title>
         <Description>* Quran Memorization Surah Competition Audio Files
* Quran Competition Surahs List</Description>
         <Attachments>broadcast_notes/26_Sura Ad duha 93.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Ayatul Kursi 2-255,256,257.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura Al Aala 87.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura Al Fatiha Hamd 1.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura Al Falaq 113.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura Al Balad 90.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura Al Asr 103.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura Al Feel 105.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura Al Qadr 97.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura Al Maoon 107.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura Al Jumua 62.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura Al Kafiroon 109.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura Al Kauthar 108.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura Al Qariah 101.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura At Teen 95.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura At Tawheed 112.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura At Takathur 102.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura Asshams 91.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura An Nasr 110.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura An Naas 114.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura AlInfitar 82.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Sura Al Quraish 106.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_Surah AlInshirah 94.mp3,broadcast_notes/26_2014 Quran Competition Surahs (1).docx</Attachments>
      </Resource>
      <Resource>
         <Id>16</Id>
         <Title>AZM Calendar</Title>
         <Description>Az Zahra Madressah 2014-15 Calendar</Description>
         <Attachments>broadcast_notes/16_AZM CALENDAR 2014_2015.xlsx</Attachments>
      </Resource>
      <Resource>
         <Id>30</Id>
         <Title>Madresaah Schedule</Title>
         <Description>Madressah and Academy Students 2014-15 Schedule</Description>
         <Attachments>broadcast_notes/30_Madressah Schedule 2014-2015.xlsx</Attachments>
      </Resource>
   </Resources>
</Result>
```

note :

```
<Description>
<strong>December 21st, 28th; Winter Break</strong>
       ~ January 4th: Madressah and
   <strong>Acadamy ResumesAZM</strong>
  will provide snacks every first Sunday of the month.
</Description>
```

When I prase  I only got the Text * ~ January 4th: Madressah and*
but what I want is to get the Whole text including the html tag .i.e  and text within it.

In short I want the Text

```
<strong>December 21st, 28th; Winter Break</strong>
       ~ January 4th: Madressah and
   <strong>Acadamy ResumesAZM</strong>
  will provide snacks every first Sunday of the month.
```

Here is my code how I m parsing the this

```
Log.e("Text Desc", parser.getValue(
                            eAnnoucements, "Description"));
```

here is my getValue() method

```
public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
    return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}
```

here is my getElementValue() method

```
public final String getElementValue(Node elem) {
    Node child;
    if (elem != null) {
        if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
            for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child
                    .getNextSibling()) {
                if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    return child.getNodeValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your data in a CDATA and then use getTextContent on the node

```
<Description>
    <![CDATA[<strong>December 21st, 28th; Winter Break</strong>
                  ~ January 4th: Madressah and
                   <strong>Acadamy ResumesAZM</strong>
                   will provide snacks every first Sunday of the month.\n]]>
 </Description>
```

CDATA http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect

This works using your xml with the CDATA section added

```
    NodeList list =  doc.getElementsByTagName("Description");

    if ( list.getLength() == 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    for ( int item = 0 ; item < list.getLength(); ++item ) {

        Node description = list.item(item);
        System.out.println("Contents:" + description.getTextContent() );

    }
```